# Does Hop Airlines allow for a personal item?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, societe-hop

Hop Airlines has a [baggage page on their website](http://www.hop.com/en/information/baggage), but has nothing on a personal item. Do they allow it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I contacted Hop Airlines on Facebook:

> Is it possible to take a backpack and a small personal item as carry on?
>
> Hi Karoly, yes, you can do that. ... Kim

So yes, they allow for it.